# Hide profile picture

Tags: views, panels, users

This is the profile page http://www.lusciousanime.com/users/ruriko
You notice there 2 duplicate profile pictures. I am using panels to layout the profile page. On the left column it uses Author Pane and the right column it uses User Profile token. I am also using Profile2 module. I want to remove the picture in the right column. How can I do this?

Comment: unset ($form['picture']);

Answer (score 1):

If you're comfortable with the views module, I would recommend adding a view that displays the user profile the way you want it and using that as the right part of the panel.  In the view, just add the fields you want displayed-- if you don't want the user profile picture, simply don't add it.